# Teleport Used for Scene Transition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steamvr

I am trying to load a new scene in Unity 3D, using the SteamVR Teleport Prefab. However, even though I have the "Move Scene" option selected, when I teleport to that object, it just goes away and doesn't actually teleport me anywhere. Is there any update or fix for this? Need this for a thesis project.

I have already looked at a question similar to this that was asked on this site, but it wasn't very clear to me. Also, both of the scenes are in the Build Settings

I have no code to show. I just used a pull-down option in the Inspector.

I expect that, when I teleport to the TeleportPoint, I should be moved to the new scene.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask], [tour] and [mcve] to improve your question

Comment: Maybe you should try 
        SceneManager.LoadScene("YourSceneName");
and import the SceneManagement Libary

Comment: Thank you @AssasinBot ! I'll try doing that